# AngularJS input.radio initial selection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to initialise/select a particular radio button within a group. I want to pass in an index number to an attribute called "selected-item".

---

### HTML

```
<div class="top">
    <radio-buttons model="colour" selected-item="1" items='colours'></radio-buttons>
    <div>{{colour}}</div>
</div>

<div class="center">
    <radio-buttons model="day" selected-item="2" items='days'></radio-buttons>
    <div>{{day}}</div>
</div>

<div class="bottom">
     <radio-buttons model="phone" selected-item="3" items="phones"></radio-buttons>
     <div>{{phone}}</div>
</div>
```

---

### Directive:

```
directives.directive('radioButtons', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            model: '=',
            items: '=',
            selectedItem: '@'
        },
        templateUrl: 'template/radio-group.html',
        link: function(scope) {
            console.log(scope.selectedItem);
            scope.onItemChange = function(item) {
                console.log(item);
                scope.model = item;
            };
        }
    };
});
```

---

### Template: radio-group.html:

```
<div ng-repeat='item in items'>
    <input
       type="radio"
       name="{{item.group}}"
       ng-value="{{item.value}}"
       ng-model="model"
       ng-change="onItemChange(item)"/>
       {{item.text}}
</div>
```

---

### Controller

```
$scope.colours= [ {
    text: "Pink",
    value: 5,
    group: "colourGroup",
    img: 'app/img/icon.jpg'
}, {
    text: "Yellow",
    value: 6,
    group: "colourGroup",
    img: 'app/img/icon.jpg'
}, {
    text: "Blue",
    value: 7,
    group: "colourGroup",
    img: 'app/img/icon.jpg'
}, {
    text: "Green",
    value: 8,
    group: "colourGroup",
    img: 'app/img/icon.jpg'
}
];

$scope.days = [ {
    text: "Monday",
    value: 9,
    group: "dayGroup"
    }, {
    text: "Tuesday",
    value: 10,
    group: "dayGroup"
    }, {
    text: "Wednesday",
    value: 11,
    group: "dayGroup"
    }, {
    text: "Thursday",
    value: 12,
    group: "dayGroup"
    }
];

$scope.phones = [ {
    text: "Android",
    group: "phoneGroup",
    value: 13
}, {
    text: "iOS",
    group: "phoneGroup",
    value: 14
}, {
    text: "Blackberry",
    group: "phoneGroup",
    value: 15
}];
```

Any help would be fantastic!

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing `ng-value="{{item.value}}"` to `value="{{item.value}}"`.

Then add `ng-checked="$index == (selectedItem - 1)"` to the input in the template.

Alternatively: `ng-checked="$index == (selectedItem - 1) || $first"` or with `$last`, if you want it to select something if you try an index that is out of range.

Comment: I've taken your first option and it works fine. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Without using value, here is another solution:

```
link: function(scope) {
    scope.model = angular.copy(scope.items[scope.selectedItem -1]);
    var setSelected = function(v) {
        var i = 0;
        for(; i < scope.items.length;i++) {
            if(scope.items[i].value === v) {
                return scope.items[i];
            }
        }
    }

    scope.$watch('model.value',function(v) {
        //because the value is out of sync with the model, have to reset the model      
        scope.model = angular.copy(setSelected(v));
    });
}
```

Note that ng-value has to be a string, and therefore ng-model. scope.model is only exposed as scope in your directive, so am using scope.model.value

```
<div ng-repeat='item in items'>
    <input
       type="radio"
       name="{{item.group}}"
       ng-value="{{item.value}}"
       ng-model="model.value" />
       {{item.text}} 
</div>
```

Comment: I have gone with tasseKATT reply below as it's a lot less code and clearer. Thank you for replying it's very much appreciated.